# How to install JDK on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I downloaded JDK from oracle website and put the unzipped folder in a directory. This is what I see when I try to run java:

```
me@ubuntu:~/jdk1.7.0_79/bin$ ./java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

above displays the version but when I try

```
me@ubuntu:~/jdk1.7.0_79/bin$ java
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

what's going on here? What is proper way to install JDK? I have been having similar issue trying to install other programs on ubuntu

Comment: By default it will seek the standard PATH. Hence why when you simply run "java" it will try to run java on the path set on your system. You can run java by doing what you did before "./java", or you can add the JDK path into the system environment path.

Comment: So as far as installing JDK is concerned is it sufficient to unzip the tar file from oracle and chmod +x and modify the PATH? Why do I need to chmod +x even though the file already has x attribute?

Comment: If it already have +x then you don't need to. But there have been some cases where after unzip the permission are not kept properly or the +x is gone from the original file. (Seen this happen when the file was unzipped on windows, placed on a share drive and then accessed on Linux - all the permission are out of whack)